# Overwrite text in a complicated filter hook

Tags: functions, filters

I am very new to PHP and WordPress. I have learned only the basics of filter hooks but this one seems to be a bit complicated. I want to replace the text `This action will let you pay a deposit of` and `for this product` preserving the value that is passed to `%s`. I am hoping that someone will be able to help me out. Thank you.

```
<?php
    echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'yith_wcdp_deposit_only_message', sprintf( __( 'This action will let you pay a deposit of <span class="deposit-price">%s</span> for this product', 'yith-woocommerce-deposits-and-down-payments' ), wc_price( $deposit_value ) ), $deposit_value ) );
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to understand if you break it down. The code in your question is exactly the the same as this:

```
$message = sprintf( __( 'This action will let you pay a deposit of <span class="deposit-price">%s</span> for this product', 'yith-woocommerce-deposits-and-down-payments' ), wc_price( $deposit_value ) );
$message = apply_filters( 'yith_wcdp_deposit_only_message', $message, $deposit_value );

echo wp_kses_post( $message );
```

If you look at it that way, you can see that the `yith_wcdp_deposit_only_message` filter is applied *after* the `%s` has been substituted with `wc_price( $deposit_value )`.

However, you can also see that the filter receives the `$deposit_value` variable as its second argument, meaning that you can use it in your filter:

```
<?php
add_filter(
    'yith_wcdp_deposit_only_message',
    function( $message, $deposit_value ) {
        $message = 'This is my new message, and the deposit value is ' . wc_price( $deposit_value );
         
        return $message;
    },
    10,
    2 // MUST be 2 to be able to use $deposit_value.
);
```

Comment: Thank you for not only answering my question but also breaking down each section and explaining the parts I thought were very complex. I learned a lot from your answer. Trying out programming career after the harsh situation due to lock down. Thank you once again.